# Is there Solid's mergeProps and spreadProps equivalent in React?

Tags: reactjs, solid-js

```js
import { mergeProps, splitProps } from "solid-js";
```

I am trying to convert a Solid-js application to React. I was asking if there is equivalent of Solid's `mergeProps` and `splitProps` in React?

For the context I am adding a half converted file as well.

```js
// import { styled } from "@stitches/react";
import React, {  FC, ReactNode, useMemo } from "react";
// import { mergeProps } from "react-aria";
import {   mergeProps,splitProps } from "solid-js";
// import { Dynamic } from "solid-js/web";

import { createStyledSystemClass, getUsedStylePropNames } from "../styled-system/system";
import { isFunction } from "../utils/assertion";
import { classNames, createClassSelector } from "../utils/css";
// import splitProps from "../utils/split-props";

import {
  DOMElements,
  ElementType,
  HopeComponent,
  HopeFactory,
  HopeFactoryStyleOptions,
  HTMLHopeComponents,
  HTMLHopeProps,
} from "./types";
// import {styled} from '@stitches/react'

// TODO: add stitches variant support

const styled: HopeFactory = <T extends ElementType>(
  component: T,
  styleOptions?: HopeFactoryStyleOptions<T>
) => {
  const hopeComponent: HopeComponent<T> = props => {
    const usedStylePropNames = getUsedStylePropNames(props);

    const propsWithDefault = mergeProps({as: component} , props);

    const [local, styleProps, others] = splitProps(
      propsWithDefault as HTMLHopeProps<any>,
      ["as", "class", "className", "__baseStyle"],
      usedStylePropNames
    );

    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/rules-of-hooks
    const __baseStyles = useMemo(() => {
      const factoryBaseStyle = isFunction(styleOptions?.baseStyle)
        ? styleOptions?.baseStyle(props as any)
        : styleOptions?.baseStyle;

      // order is important for css override
      return [factoryBaseStyle, local.__baseStyle];
    },[local.__baseStyle, props]);

    const classes = () => {
      return classNames(
        styleOptions?.baseClass, // In order to target the component in stitches css method and prop, like any other Hope UI components.
        local.class,
        local.className,
        createStyledSystemClass(styleProps, __baseStyles)
      );
    };
    const elements: keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements = local.as ?? "div"

    const Dynamic: FC<{as: any, children: ReactNode}> = ({ as, children, ...props }) => {    
        return React.createElement(
            elements[as] || elements, 
            props, 
            children
      );
    }
    

    return <Dynamic className={classes()} {...others} >{component}</Dynamic>;
  };

  // In order to target the component in stitches css method and prop, like any other Hope UI components.
  hopeComponent.toString = () =>
    styleOptions?.baseClass ? createClassSelector(styleOptions.baseClass) : "";

  return hopeComponent;
};

function factory() {
  const cache = new Map<DOMElements, HopeComponent<DOMElements>>();

  return new Proxy(styled, {
    /**
     * @example
     * const Div = hope("div")
     * const WithHope = hope(AnotherComponent)
     */
    apply(target, thisArg, argArray: [ElementType, HopeFactoryStyleOptions<ElementType>]) {
      return styled(...argArray);
    },

    /**
     * @example
     * <hope.div />
     */
    get(_, element: DOMElements) {
      if (!cache.has(element)) {
        cache.set(element, styled(element));
      }
      return cache.get(element);
    },
  }) as HopeFactory & HTMLHopeComponents;
}

export const hope = factory();
```

I tried ract-aria `mergeProps()` didn't worked also wrote a split props function that didn't worked as well.

Answer (score 0):

The regular spread and rest syntax (`...`) will suffice.

Solid can not use rest and spread syntax for splitting and merging props because the props object is a proxy object that converts a property access to a function call in order to preserve the reactivity of the passed props. Splitting and merging Solid's props using `...` syntax will give you static values, discarding the proxy object in the process. So Solid needs `mergeProps` and `splitProps` helpers to provide similar functionality to spread and rest syntax while preserving the reactivity.

However, React's props are plain objects and does not require proxy because React renders whole DOM tree with each state update. If you remember, Solid employs fine grained reactivity using actual DOM elements, meaning it does not render whole DOM tree but only small portion of it where state gets updated. But React uses virtual DOM and renders whole DOM with each state update, while diffing and batching previously rendered tree to minimize the work.

Now, to answer your question, you do not need `mergeProps` or `splitProps` in React because the rest and spread syntax gives you that functionality.

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';

export function App(props) {
  const { name, ...rest } = props;
  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <h1>Hello {name}!</h1>
      <p>{JSON.stringify(rest)}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

const person = { name: 'John Doe', age: 22 };
const company = { company: 'Acme inc.' };
const address = { city: 'LA', state: 'CA' };

const props = { ...person, ...company, address };

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector('#root')).render(
  <App {...props} />
);
```